# How to use benefit

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions

I want to make a sentence with `benefit`. Which form is correct?

```
A gives benefit to B by C
A benefit B from C
A benefit B with C
```

here:

```
A is what giving benefit
B is who receives the benefit
C is the benefit received
```

Example:

> This research benefits scientists of easier detection of TB.

Comment: Could you give specific examples of the `C` that would be used in this context?

Comment: @Barmar eg. this research benefits scientists of easier detection of TB

Comment: Did you made the example up or is ir a real example taken from some english source? I don't remember ever having seen that usages.

Comment: @user1598390 this is made by me. I want to make a correct sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it as:

> This research benefits scientists by providing easier detection of TB.

or:

> This research benefits scientists through easier detection of TB.